# VideoView.getDuration returns wrong value;

Tags: android, android-videoview

I use videoview  to display following video https://ellovidsout.s3.amazonaws.com/877/9/1421668953.mp4.m3u8
At the end of the video I check `getCurrentPosition()` vs `getDuration()`.
The current position is 219418.0. While `getDuration` returns 205000.0.
So duration is 14 seconds less then real length. That also happens with my other video.

Answer (score 0):

The getDuration() method of VideoView calculates the duration according to the duration **that is declared in the .m3u8 manifest** for each .ts file.

So, if the declaration is not accurate there will be a difference between getDuration() and the actual duration as you observe it by using getCurrentPosition().

Your .m3u8 example file is actually a 'playlist manifest' that refers to 3 different .m3u8 stream manifests (selected according to bandwidth), so if we look at one of the stream manifests it refers to, it will look like this:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:YES
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:11
#EXTINF:10.880000,
1000k_1421668953.mp400000.ts
#EXTINF:10.800000,
1000k_1421668953.mp400001.ts
#EXTINF:10.800000,
1000k_1421668953.mp400002.ts
#EXTINF:10.800000,
1000k_1421668953.mp400003.ts
#EXTINF:7.200000,
1000k_1421668953.mp400004.ts
#EXTINF:10.800000,
1000k_1421668953.mp400005.ts
...
```

The '#EXTINF:10.880000' above each .ts link is the .ts duration declaration that is used by getDuration() to sum the total video duration.

By the way, when I ran my code with this video, the duration I got by using getDuration() was actually 199330, which is slightly different from what you observed back then. But this is exactly the sum of all the duration declarations.